# How to overlay buttons on form background image

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

Sample background image:

[image: Sample background image]

I am working on a winforms application using C# 2019. I have created a form with a background image shown by the image above (for illustration purposes only). What I want to do is place buttons on top of button A and B so that when the form is resized the button resizes too and continues to cover button a and b. This should remain the case for all screen sizes.

My problem is when the form is moved to a screen of a different size, then my buttons and buttons on the background image don't align. How can this be fixed.

I have tried using dock and anchor properties as well as panels and tablelayout controls without success. Please help.

Comment: Off the top of my head: Place them in a Panel with all anchors on. Then place that Panel in a TableLayoutPanel and set the dimensions to percent. The TLP should also be anchored or docked to resize with the form

Comment: Maybe use like:
`button1.Location = new Point(20, this.Size.Height-30);` `button2.Location = new Point(100, this.Size.Height-30);` Something like this put in Form1 loading event?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `TableLayoutPanel` to your form with five columns and three rows:

```
Column 0: width to left of "Button A"
Column 1: width of "Button A"
Column 2: width between "Button A" and "Button B"
Column 3: width of "Button B"
Column 4: width to right of "Button B"

Row 0: height above "Button A" and "Button B"
Row 1: height of "Button A" and "Button B"
Row 2: height below "Button A" and "Button B"
```

The column widths and row heights would all be set as percentages. The `TableLayoutPanel` would cover the same area as the image, so `Dock` set to `Fill` if the image covers the whole form. Now the form, image and `TableLayoutPanel` will all expand and contract in unison. You can now place `Button` controls in the cells over "Button A" and "Button B" in your image and set their `Dock` property to `Fill` as well and you'll get the effect you want.

EDIT:

The alternative would be to not use controls at all and handle the `MouseClick` event of the form, then do a bit of arithmetic to determine whether the user clicked on those virtual buttons. You wouldn't get the animation provided by `Button` controls that way though.

Comment: Can I get in touch with you regarding first suggestion? You can email on mutongigava007@gmail.com

Comment: @MutongiGava, sorry, no. That's not what sites like this are about. Do your research, implement what you can for yourself and then ask another question if you encounter a specific issue.